# Pass object back to function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code where I'm attempting to pass the btn object back to where the handleMemberAction was called, so that some classes can be added or removed.  But I've not had any luck doing so. How can this be done?

```
var handleMemberAction;

handleMemberAction = function(selector, action_path, success_handler) {
  return $(document).on("click", ".member-row " + selector, function(e) {
    var btn, member_id, request;
    btn = $(this);
    btn.text(btn.data("loading-text"));
    member_id = btn.parents(".member-row").data("id");
    request = {
      transfer_id: btn.parents(".member-row").data("transfer"),
      org_id: $("#club_members").data("org")
    };
    return SF.action.post("action/transfer/" + action_path, request, success_handler);
  });
};

handleMemberAction(".cancel_transfer", "cancel", function(e, btn) {
  return btn.removeClass("btn-warning cancel_transfer").addClass("btn-default transfer").text("Transfer");
});
```

Comment: This entirely depends on what `SF.action.post` passes into the 3rd argument (where you are passing `success_handler`)

Comment: take out your code out of that function . and console.log each variable first to know in which part your code stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `success_handler` within an anonymous function that you pass to the post function, rather than passing `success_handler` directly. Then you can propagate anything you want through to your callback that you specify when calling `handleMemberAction`.

```
return SF.action.post("action/transfer/" + action_path, request, function (postCallbackData) {
    success_handler(postCallbackData, btn);
});
```

Note, I'm not sure what SF.action.post calls your function with, but I've just passed it on assuming the first argument you have there is correct.